# Arrange 2 controllers in same column

Tags: wpf, grid, alignment

I have `ListView` `Column` with Slider and `TextBlock` to show the `Slider` value:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate2">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Slider Grid.Column="0" Name="sliderColumn" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TickPlacement="None"
            Minimum="0" Maximum="50" Value="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Width="70"
            TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sliderColumn, StringFormat={}x{0}}" FontSize="11" Foreground="White" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is result:

[image]

And when the `Slider` value changing `TextBlock` is hidden by the Slider:

[image]

What's wrong with my code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To resolve your problem you must add your **TextBlock** to column 1, and too use `HorizontalAlign` property to align your `TextBlock` in the left, adding an little left `Margin` to stay with best visual.

The following code solves your problem:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyDataTemplate2">

<Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="70" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Slider Grid.Column="0" Name="sliderColumn" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"  TickPlacement="None"
            Minimum="0" Maximum="50" Value="1" Style="{StaticResource SliderStyle}" Width="70" TickFrequency="1" IsSnapToTickEnabled="True"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Margin="5,0,0,0"  Text="{Binding Path=Value, ElementName=sliderColumn, StringFormat={}x{0}}" FontSize="11" Foreground="black" 
            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your TextBlock is in the same column as your Slider, try putting it in the `Grid.Column="1"` instead of 0. If this was intended, you could also put a margin on either of the blocks to put a space between the two.